# ScannerBrowser depreciated ImageKit OSX Yosemite

Tags: objective-c, osx-yosemite, imagekit

I found an example on the website of Apple developers about the library looking ImageKit in which scanners connected but there is a problem because when I connect my scanner is not detected, I ran the program and tells me there is a function `NSBeginAlertSheet` deprecated.
Somebody help me solve problems.

The link is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ScannerBrowser/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008915-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSBeginAlertSheet` was deprecated in OS X 10.10 and it is recommended to use `NSAlert` instead.  Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSBeginAlertSheet

That specific error is not related to ImageKit.